# Unable to run a stored procedure in snowflake database

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE wh.sp_schema.my_sp(arg1 STRING, arg2 STRING)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS 
$$
 stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
  {sqlText: `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE wh.table_schema.RAW_`+arg2+`_`+arg1+` LIKE wh.temp_schema.RAW_`+arg2+`_TEMPLATE`}
  );
rs = stmt.execute();
rs.next();
output = rs.getColumnValue(1);
return output;
$$
;
```

when i create the above stored procedure - below message is displayed

```
Function my_sp successfully created.
```

when i run the stored procedure from the worksheet using

```
CALL my_sp('2018','abc');
```

I see the below error:

```
SQL compilation error: Invalid identifier my_sp
```

I even tried running using fully qualified name for the stored procedure:

```
CALL wh.sp_schema.my_sp('2018','abc');
```

I still see the below error:

```
SQL compilation error: Invalid identifier my_sp.
```

Also, i would like to know a command to see if my stored procedure has been created or not.
I've looked in the snowflake UI, under 'wh" warehouse and "sp_schema" schema, but could not see anything(stored procedures) other than tables.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple case of a grants issue.  As SECURITYADMIN, if you apply the necessary grants to the role you're using,

```
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE wh TO ROLE <role>;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA wh.sp_schema TO ROLE <role>;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA wh.sp_schema TO ROLE <role>;
```

you'll get past this ambiquous error and get to the next real error

```
JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: arg2 is not defined in MY_SP
```

Which is due to javascript SP parameters being case sensitive, so you need to modify the code as follows (change arg to ARG):

```
{sqlText: `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE wh.table_schema.RAW_`+ARG2+`_`+ARG1+` LIKE wh.temp_schema.RAW_`+ARG2+`_TEMPLATE`}
```

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does not support `Stored Procedures. They are implementing`javascript` based APIs for it, but it's still in draft mode.

Here's the [link](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/LIMITEDACCESS/stored-procedures-api.html) to their APIs (Note **Draft Document** is written on right hand side).

and here's the [link](https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008EKTr9SAH/is-there-a-plan-on-the-roadmap-for-stored-procedures) to a ticket on their support forum where they've confirmed it.

Comment: Obviously this is now wrong per May, 2019.  Asker must have had early access (and should have noted about that)...

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious possibilities why this may go wrong:

1. You've implicitly donated the procedure ownership to a `ROLE` you don't have
2. There is now a mismatch between the procedure and call type signatures.  Verify that there is a `wh.sp_schema.my_sp(STRING, STRING)` and that your call is like 
   `CALL wh.sp_schema.my_sp('2018'::STRING,'abc'::STRING);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve the error by following query syntax.

CALL database_name.schema.MY_SP('database_name','schema');